# How to send user inputs back to the form if check failed with express validation and also the errors?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Sorry for the bad title, didn't know how to phrase it. Learn node.js at the moment and I have the following problem.

I use the edge template framework. I use express validation as a middleware.

All things still work well - but how can I send/restore the user input into the fields again and also trow the errors as user information?

This is my code at the moment:

```
// Registration POST request
router.post('/register',
    userController.verifyRegister,
    userController.checkUserExists,
    userController.registerUser,
    authController.login
);

...
userController.js
... some code before ...

exports.verifyRegister = async (req, res, next) => {
    req.sanitizeBody('username');
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username should not be empty!').notEmpty();
    req.sanitizeBody('email');
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email should not be empty').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'You must enter a valid email to register').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password should not be empty').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Password confirmation should not be empty').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Both passwords does not match!').equals(req.body.password);

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors) {
        console.log(errors);
        //res.json(req.body.errors); //tried - no work?!?!
        res.redirect('back')
        return;
    }
    next();
}
// Check if the user already exists Will hook it up later
... works if all inputs are correct!! ...
```

I've searched and tried a lot - but I don't know to solve this.

Any ideas how to?

Thanks.

ps: I'm looking for a person who develop with me together over git. I want to learn git also how to develop a small app over git. Thanks.

Comment: ups - forggot: I don't whant to use flash ... or is it the better solution? Whant to learn without it.

Comment: verifyRegister() is async and as such it returns a promise. However, you do not `await` for the request.validationErrors() and therefore your if check does not return true.

Answer (score 0):

`verifyRegister()` is async and as such it returns a promise. However, you do not `await` for the request.validationErrors() and therefore your if check does not return true.

```
exports.verifyRegister = async (req, res, next) => {
    ...

    const errors = await req.validationErrors();
    if(errors) {
        console.log(errors);
        return res.redirect('back');
        
    }
    next();
}
```

If this answer helps you solve the issue, **consider** accepting it as valid answer or upvoting it. Thanks.